# Displaying records number in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to display number of records of AngularJS , sample "1 to 10 of 15 records". Everything is working and I want to apply the page number. I'm using dir-paginate AngularJS , Is there easy way to achieve this? really appreciate your help. Here is my code:
HTML CODE:

```
<table class="primary-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Contact Number</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Date Added</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbodyrow">
        <tr ng-if="members.length==0"><td colspan="11">No Records</td></tr>
        <tr ng-if="members.length>0" dir-paginate="member in members|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5">
            <td>{{ member.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.contact }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.address }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.position }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ member.dateadded }}</td>
            <td>Edit</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot class="tfootrow">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="11">
                <div class="grid2">
                    <div><!--number of records info here--></div>
                    <div>
                        <dir-pagination-controls max-size="5"
                            direction-links="true" boundary-links="true" >
                        </dir-pagination-controls>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
angular.module('app', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
angular.module('app').controller('AdminController', function($scope, $http){
  this.fetch = function(){
    $http.get("../Ajax/Administrator/fetch.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.members  = response.data;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know the page size you can use a model variable to assign the value and access the total lentgh of the array using array.length

```
 <h3> 1 to {{ pageSize }} of {{members.length}} records</h3>
```

**[DEMO USING PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview)**